# 1064 SQL syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't figure out what's wrong with this SQL syntax. I'm using MySQL 3.3.1

All of these empty fields are either varchar or text.
The reason for so many empty fields is due to UI requirements, I want to insert the record with only basic info, then populate the details later.

```
INSERT INTO projtrackingoppor(address,latLong,stage,projType,dateInitiated,designProjNumber,constrProjNumber,designProjManager,clientContact,client,notes,nextAction,dueDate,designCriteria,designBearingCapacity,designGroundMotion_SLS,allowableSettlement_SLS,allowableLateralDisplacement_SLS,designGroundMotion_ULS,allowableSettlement_ULS,allowableLateralDisplacement_ULS,otherDeisgnCriteria,siteDescription,subsurfaceConditions,as-BuiltImprovementType_1,as-BuiltDiameter_1,as-BuiltDepth_1,as-BuiltSpacing_1,as-BuiltPrice_1,commentsOnPrice_1,proposedImprovementType_2,proposedDiameter_2,proposedDepth_2,proposedSpacing_2,proposedPrice_2,commentsOnPrice_2,proposedImprovementType_3,proposedDiameter_3,proposedDepth_3,proposedSpacing_3,proposedPrice_3,commentsOnPrice_3,proposedImprovementType_4,proposedDiameter_4,proposedDepth_4,proposedSpacing_4,proposedPrice_4,commentsOnPrice_4,proposedImprovementType_5,proposedDiameter_5,proposedDepth_5,proposedSpacing_5,proposedPrice_5,commentsOnPrice_5,soilDescription_a,Ic_a,midlayerDepth_a,finesContent_a,WC_a,LL_a,PI_a,PRE_qtncs_N160cs_a,POST_qtncs_N160cs_a,comments_a,soilDescription_b,Ic_b,midlayerDepth_b,finesContent_b,WC_b,LL_b,PI_b,PRE_qtncs_N160cs_b,POST_qtncs_N160cs_b,comments_b,soilDescription_c,Ic_c,midlayerDepth_c,finesContent_c,WC_c,LL_c,PI_c,PRE_qtncs_N160cs_c,POST_qtncs_N160cs_c,comments_c) VALUES ("test new add job","-40.07807143,175.73730469","4","4","2013-06-03","13123","","","","","","","0000-00-00","0","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","")
```

The error message is

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near
>   'as-BuiltImprovementType_1,as-BuiltDiameter_1,as-BuiltDepth_1,as-BuiltSpacing_1,a'
>   at line 1

Comment: MySQL 3.3.1?! and then what, php 3.4?

Comment: maybe mysql doesn't like the "as-Built" -

Comment: Have you ever heard of "new line"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-` (hyphen) character is a reserved character in MySQL. To use it in the name of a column, a table etc. the name must be quoted.

See the MySQL docs, [9.2 Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html).

Note: While you *can* use such names by quoting them (including them in backticks), I'd advise against it, because it might cause problems down the road, e.g. with tools that do not properly quote names, or if you later switch DBMS. Just stick to letters, numbers and underscore.

Answer (score 3):

"AS" is a reserved MySQL-word.

Surround your fields with ``, like:

```
`as-BuiltDiameter_1`
```

Comment: Or even better, respect the restrictions on names and stick to letters, numbers and underscore. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637496/do-underscores-in-mysql-table-names-cause-issues

Comment: -1 incorrect. The "AS" is no problem, the hyphen is. Try using an identifier like "as_built" - MySQL will not complain.